# Solve for $x$, $2\cdot 3^{x+1}-3^{-x} \le 5$

Tags: calculus

$2\cdot 3^{x+1}-3^{-x} \le 5$

I tried:
$$2\cdot 3^{x+1}-3^{-x} \le 5 \Leftrightarrow 2 \cdot 3^x \cdot 3 - \frac{1}{3^x} \ge 5 \Leftrightarrow \frac{6\cdot 3^x}{1}-\frac{1}{3^x}\ge 5 \Leftrightarrow \frac{3^x(6\cdot 3^x)}{3^x} \ge 5 \Leftrightarrow  \\-(6\cdot 3^x) \ge 5 \Leftrightarrow 6\cdot 3^x \le -5 \Leftrightarrow 3^x \le -\frac{5}{6} \Leftrightarrow -3^x \ge \frac{5}{6} \Leftrightarrow -x \ge \log_3{\frac{5}{6}} \Leftrightarrow x \le -\log_3{\frac{5}{6}}$$

But my book says the solution is $x \le 0$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You reversed the inequality at the very first step, then you lost the 2nd term of the difference two steps later.

Answer (score 1):

It's a standard trick when you see $a^x$ and $a^{-x}$ to multiply through by $a^x$ and see if a quadratic equation appears.  In this case, pull one factor of 3 out of the first term, bring the $5$ over to left side and multiply by $3^x$ to get

$$6\cdot 3^{2x}-5\cdot 3^x -1 \leq 0.$$

This factors:

$$(6\cdot 3^x+1)(3^x-1) \leq 0.$$

The first factor is always positive, so we must have $3^x-1\leq 0.$  So $3^x\leq 1$, and hence $x\leq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

substitute $y=3^x$  in 
$$
6\cdot 3^x-\frac{1}{3^x}\le 5
$$
and , noting that $y=3^x>0 \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, solve:
$$
6y^2-1\le 5y
$$